# Change TabBar IOS

Tags: ios, tabbar

I am developing an application with Xcode for iOS. The application is about taking picture from the camera or picking from the gallery, saving it and sharing it to Facebook.

In my first view, I have a `UITabBar` (1), when I click on `Take picture` button a `UIActionSheet` appears like this. (2)

When I choose to take a picture from the gallery, for example I choose the picture  and I display it , is it possible to change the `UITabBar` from (1) to (3) when I display the picture that I choose and is it possible to change the `UITabBar` to something like picture (4) when I save the picture ?

Here is the image:

[image]

PS: In the facebook page and twitter page i click on those button to go to facebook page and twitter page.

Sorry for my Bad English and Thanks in advance

Comment: `UITabBar`s are designed as a way for switching between multiple screens in the app. What you're trying to do is better accomplished with a [`UIToolbar`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html), as it allows you to add buttons with custom actions, and change them around at any time.